# Where can I download MyUnity visual?

Tags: unity, customization, myunity

There is a MyUnity version that can tweak the unity desktop in a visual way like so

[My unity visual Youtube video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDCxAx1kLPw).

In the [myunity PPA](https://launchpad.net/myunity) and the [homepage](http://www.uielinux.org/myunity/), there is no beta / alpha download option.

My question is where can I download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is part of the MyUnity 4.0 development branch, not yet released and not yet usable.

You cannot install it at the moment as far as I know.

Comment: on there [site](http://www.uielinux.org/myunity/) they have mention that u can download . and @blade19899 doesn't mention for MyUnity 4.0.

Comment: @Gaurav_Java that is MyUnity3, its cool but does not have the visual customization that he is looking for as in the Youtube video he shows. MyUnity 3 can be installed for 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04 using the method you have in your answer. MyUnity 4 is still not released.

Comment: Aah i see .. that i not see ... my fault  . thanks +1

Answer (score -1):

The application provides a user-friendly way to adjust, tweak and customize part of the Unity desktop.

**MyUnity** is available to install in Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10 using the following **PPA**  to your **Software Sources** or by running the following two commands via

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:myunity/ppa`
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install myunity`

MyUnity has also recently been accepted into the Ubuntu 12.04 repositories. This will make installation of the application easy as it is available to install direct from the Ubuntu Software Centre in Ubuntu 12.04 – no PPAs needed

Amongst its features are: -

- Change Dash, Launcher and Panel transparency
- Adjust Dash blur
- Display ‘home’, ‘trash’ and mounted drives on the desktop
- Adjust launcher size, backlights and hiding preferences
- Tweak font settings, including size, RGBA and hinting
- The revamped interface introduces a ‘sliding’ widget for switching
  between sections